# I am trying to submit a form on an external url but i get error: The action you have requested is not allowed

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to automate a form submitting on cron to an external url
after i made the script i get this error from the external site

```
An Error Was Encountered

The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

Is there anyway i can solve this problem?

here is the curl code

```
$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.extsite.com/submit"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'contenttitle' => '$title',
  'contentpath' => '$path',
  'submit' => 'submit'
  ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo "$result";
```

Answer (score 1):

If the site's admins do not want that somebody submits forms automatically they may check the `Origin` HTTP header and check if it belongs to their domain. If not they will return that error message.

If it's a legal action you are about to do, you may ask the site admins per email.

Comment: So there is no other way i can do this automatically ?

Comment: I currently don't know if the 'Origin' header is the problem. If so, you may spoof it. But I would ask admins to avoid you from getting trouble.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the quotes around the variables

```
 '$title' should be just $title
```

Also maybe check if your submitting the correct parameters? 'submit'=>'submit' just doesnt look right to me

Id say try to print_r your array and see if it even comes out fine.

Comment: Even if i change that i get the same error from the external site